# Generate the DH series

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

I see from [this SMBC comic](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/puzzle-time) that Zach Weinersmith is offering a generous 14 points to anybody who can find a way of generating the following series:

```
0, 1, 4, -13, -133, 52, 53, -155
```

Now, we all know that there are infinite ways of generating any given numeric series, so Zach is clearly just giving those points away. But what's the *shortest* code that will do it?

I'll be particularly impressed if anyone can beat 25 bytes, particularly in a non-golfing language, since that's what it takes to write the following reference implementation in Python:

```
0,1,4,-13,-133,52,53,-155
```

The output can be in whichever format works best for you:

1. a program that spits out plaintext representation of signed decimal numbers
2. an expression that evaluates to a static sequence of numeric objects with these values (as in my Python example)
3. an expression for `f(n)` that returns the `n`th value of the sequence.  You can choose a zero-based or one-based convention for `n` as you wish and need not worry what the expression produces subsequent to the known elements.  (By "expression" here, I mean let's not count the characters in the function prototype itself, and let's say you can assume `n` is pre-initialized.)

Longer sequences (including infinite sequences) are permitted provided the first 8 elements match Weinersmith's DH Series above. The ninth and subsequent elements, if present, can be anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
“ĊĊḊḢṬ3gƈ¢‘I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc6RriNdD3cA0aKHO9cYpx/rOLToUcMMz///AQ)

#### Explanation

```
“ĊĊḊḢṬ3gƈ¢‘      String representing code points
           I     Consecutive increments
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 75 Bytes

0-Indexing
prints a underscore separeted string till the n th value

```
<?=+$e;for(;$i++<$argn;)echo _,$e+=[185,1,7-4*$e-log($e)^0,-17,-120][$i%5];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zNTay5rK3@29jb6utkmqdll@kYa2Sqa1tA5a11kxNzshXiNdRSdW2jTa0MNUx1DHXNdFSSdXNyU/XUEnVjDPQ0TU0B2Ijg9holUxV01jr//8B)

### Expanded

```
<?=+$e; #Output zero 0 th value
for(;$i++<$argn;) # loop till reach input n 
  echo _,$e+=[185,1,7-4*$e-log($e)^0,-17,-120][$i%5];
# Output and assign the next value in sequence
```

### Steps depending on mod 5 start with 1

1: plus 1

2: plus 7 minus 4 times last value minus natural logarithm of last value cast to int

3: minus 17

4: minus 120

0: plus 185

[Natural logarithm](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php)

### PHP, 33 Bytes

prints a string representation

```
<?="[0,1,4,-13,-133,52,53,-155]";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb6sUbaBjqGOio2toDMLGOqZGOqYgpqlprJL1//8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 20 bytes

```
•3—ι]½ý.¢Σ”•6¡4'-:.¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMi40cNU87tjD209/BevUOLzi1@1DAXKGp2aKGJuq6V3qGl//9HG@gY6pjo6Boag7CxjqmRjimIaWoaCwA)

**Uses:** 16364176412061856164208

**Replace the 6's with commas (split on 6):**
`['1', '3', '417', '4120', '185', '1', '4208']`

**Replace 4's with negative symbol:**
`['1', '3', '-17', '-120', '185', '1', '-208']`

**Undelta.**

---

Simpler approach (turned out worse):
`•5Û€ïÛ†!eŽΓ•8BR7¡6'-:`

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 17 Bytes

```
153B-*“¡¢¥Æ⁵45ɓ‘×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASAA3///MTUzQi0q4oCcwqHCosKlw4bigbU0NcmT4oCYw5f//w)

**Explanation:**

```
153B-*
```

decode the signs from the binary digits of 153

```
“¡¢¥Æ⁵45ɓ‘
```

the magnitudes of the numbers represented as a code-page index list

```
×
```

elementwise multiplication

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 37 bytes

```python
for i in 'ÝÞáÐXđĒB':print(ord(i)-221)
```

Comment: That is great—I fiddled with that approach briefly myself but couldn't get there. Note that you could make it a list comprehension and ditch the `print` to achieve a result of type 2

Comment: Welcome to the site! You don't need the space after the `in`.

Comment: Or say `ord('ÝÞáÐXđĒB'[n])-221` for an even shorter answer, of type 3

Comment: This works nicely, but Python only supports non-UTF-8 encodings with a magic comment (which would have to be counted towards the score).  With UTF-8, your code is 43 bytes long.

Comment: You can remove a space between `in` and the string, so `i in'ÝÞá`

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
"ÈÉÌ»Cüý-"ÇƵ%-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/8wNWFiMWX//yLDiMOJw4zCu0PDvMO9LSLDh8a1JS3//w)

**Explanation**

```
"ÈÉÌ»Cüý-"      # push this string
          Ç     # convert to code points
           Ƶ%-  # subtract 200 from each
```

#### Previous 15 bytes solution

```
•∍ÉΣ-ú—("o•3ô¬-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOiRx29hzvPLdY9vOtRwxQNpXygkPHhLYfW6P7/DwA)

**Explanation**

```
•∍ÉΣ-ú—("o•       # push the number 1551561591420222072080
           3ô     # split into pieces of 3
             ¬-   # subtract the first element from all elements
```

Comment: Way better than mine, admittedly I just wanted to try using undelta.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yeah I'm glad you did. I was unsure what it was until I saw you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 11 + 1 (`-n`) = 12 bytes

```
0γ4π./
```

[Try here](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=0%CE%B34%CF%80%F0%9D%90%8D%F0%9D%90%B2%F0%9D%90%8D.%2F%F0%9D%95%A5%F0%9D%90%8D&n=true)

Note: might not work in the future. For reference, this works for commit [db32a5e](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/commit/db32a5e120d9e2fd669201d35e66c657704ee99d).

Explanation:

```
0γ4π./ Push 0
 γ          Push 1
  4         Push 4
   π        Push 13
           Negate
           Push 133
           Negate
       .    Push 52
        /   Push 53
           Push 155
           Negate
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 79 bytes

```
s={-22,-83,408,-489,-25};i=2;While[i!=-1,t=Join[{i},Accumulate[s]+i];i--;s=t];s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#BcHNCkBAEADgV@FGZopFraYprk5uDtseJDLlp@w6ybOv71s5JI5fVApQl1DlGrDSDaCqPxJWNG6yL0ZixgI895ec5pUPunl@jmef/GKczcSSIJJjb8mlYbjl9FG7hh8)

in order to run on mathics the original code needs 2 more bytes

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, 26 bytes

```
'!ñð7¯À½¼'80g-nao90.
```

Standard unicode solution, same as the other answers. Sad I couldn't get to 25.